# How to transfer a char * into a 2d char array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to take a `char *`, which represents a single word and i got the `char *` from a function, and put it into a 2d array but instead it just repeats the first letter of each word several times. the output looks like this

```
ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvoooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

and my input file is

```
three
versions
of
simple
with
spell
check
checking
program
we
will
write
```

I am not sure how to correctly transfer a char * into a 2d array
here are all the functions i am using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dict.h"



bool is_valid_entry( int strLength, char entry[] ){

    if( entry[0] != '"' && !isalpha(entry[0]) && entry[0] != '\''  ){
        return false;
    }

    strLength--; /* to allow for the zero index of the array*/

    for ( int i=1; i < strLength; i++ )
        if ( !isalpha( entry[i] ) ){

            return false;
        }

    if (!isalpha( entry[strLength] ) && !ispunct( entry[strLength] ) && entry[strLength] != '"' && entry[strLength] != '\'' ){

        return false;
    }
return true;/* if the entry passes all of the tests the function will return true meaning the the word is valid*/ 

}/* ends is_valid_entry( int strlength, char entry[] )*/



char * normalize( int strLength, char entry[], char output[] ){

    strLength--;/* to allow for the zero index of an array*/
    int j = 0;

    for( int i = 0;i < strLength; i++){/* converts all of the elements in the entry[] to lower case*/
        if (isupper( entry[i] ) ){
            entry[i] = tolower( entry[i] );
        }
    }

    if( ( entry[0] == '"' && entry[strLength] == '"' ) || (entry[0] == '\'' && entry[strLength] == '\'' ) ) {
        for(int i=1 ; i < strLength ; i++,j++ ){ 
            output[j] = entry[i];
        }
        output[j] = '\0';/* removes the last character which is either a '"' ir a '\''*/
        return output;/* returns the noramlized word*/

        }else if( entry[0] == '"' || entry[0] == '\'' ){
            for(int i = 1; j < strLength; i++, j++ ){/*i=1 in order to skip the first element in the entry arrary*/
                output[j] = entry[i];
            }
            output[j] = '\0';
            return output;/* returns the noramlized word*/

        } else if( entry[strLength] == '"' || ispunct( entry[strLength] ) || entry[strLength] == '\''){
                for(int i = 0;j < strLength; i++,j++ ){
                    output[j] = entry[i];
                }
                output[j] = '\0';
                return output;/* returns the noramlized word*/
            }


return entry;/* returns the original array since it does not need to be normalized*/

}/* ends normalize( int strlength, char entry[], char output[] )*/
    void load_dict(char *fileName, char dictionary[30000][31]) {

    FILE *fdict;
    fdict = fopen( fileName, "r" );/* file pointer for the dictionary file*/
    char *normDictWord;
    char normDict [33]; 

    int strLength,i,j,ch;    
    if ( fdict == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file: %s\n", fileName );/*checks to make sure the dictionary file can be opened*/
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; (ch = fgetc( fdict ) ) != EOF; i++ ) {          

        char word[33] = "";/* resets the array*/


        for (strLength = 0; !isspace( ch ) ; strLength++ ){
            word[strLength] = ch;
            ch = fgetc( fdict );            
                }

        if (is_valid_entry( strLength , word ) ){
            normDictWord = normalize( strLength , word , normDict );/*normalize then do the linear search then print the word if it is not found in the dictionary*/

            for(j = 0; j <= 31;j++){
                dictionary[i][j] = * normDictWord ;
                printf("%c",dictionary[i][j]);
            }

        }


    }
    fclose( fdict ); 
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to put `char *` in `1-D array` right?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot completely understand your code, fix formatting, and add some parts that are missing (otherwise I can't test it). However:

```
dictionary[i][j] = * normDictWord;
```

should be something like:

```
dictionary[i][j] = * (normDictWord + j);
```

or equivalently:

```
dictionary[i][j] = normDictWord[j] ;
```

Comment: thank you but now it will only print one word. why does i not increase?

Comment: are you sure i does not incease? Try to print it.

Answer (score 1):

Key problem (@pez)

```
  for (j = 0; j <= 31; j++) {
    // dictionary[i][j] = *normDictWord;
    dictionary[i][j] = normDictWord[j];
    printf("%c", dictionary[i][j]);
  }
```

Some other problems:

Original code will loop endlessly should the `EOF` condition occur before a space does.  `isspace(EOF)` is false.  This loop also does not prevent overrun.

```
char word[33] = "";

// for (strLength = 0; !isspace(ch); strLength++) {
for (strLength = 0; !isspace(ch) && ch != EOF && strLength < sizeof word; strLength++) {
  word[strLength] = ch;
  ch = fgetc(fdict);
}
```

The following does not "converts all of the elements in the entry[] to lower case",  only ellements `[0 ]... [original_string_length-2]`.  Maybe code should do `strLength--;` *after* the loop.

```
strLength--;/* to allow for the zero index of an array*/
...
for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {/* */
  ...
```